# Bind JSON results to dropdown

Tags: javascript, json, drop-down-menu

I get a JSON results from an API. I want to bind the result's key pairs into a dropdown.
But below code bind value pairs into a dropdown.
For example I have JSON result as following.
{
    "AED": "United Arab Emirates Dirham",
    "AFN": "Afghan Afghani",
    "ALL": "Albanian Lek",
    "AMD": "Armenian Dram"
}

My dropdown should contain AED, AFN, ALL and AMD.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
    url: 'http://openexchangerates.org/api/currencies.json',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(result) {
         $.each(result, function() {
            $("#drpDown").append(
                $('<option/>', {
                    value: this,
                    html: this
                })
            );
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you need to be assigning two different things. Looking at the jQuery documentation, it looks like

```
$.each(result, function(key, value) {
        $("#drpDown").append(
            $('<option/>', {
                value: key,
                html: value
            })
        );
```

is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The each function accepts two parameters, the first is the collection (called result here), the second is an anonymous function which you want to add key, value parameters to, then you'll be able retrieve those key/value pairs and iterate over them.

**[jsfiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/altescape/gb71vhxa/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://openexchangerates.org/api/currencies.json',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(result) {
            $.each(result, function(key, value) {
                $("#drpDown").append(
                    $('<option/>', {
                        value: key,
                        html: value
                    })
                );
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I expect to bind AED, AFN, ALL and AMD. Not United Arab Emirates Dirham, Afghan Afghani, Albanian Lek....

Comment: @SivakumarPiratheeban So you want the key in both? Then set both value and html to key.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: key is not defined

Comment: @HamHamJ why value: key is not supported?

Comment: As HamHamJ answered already I've updated the jsfiddle to match what you want, cannot quite understand the difficulty though. http://jsfiddle.net/altescape/gb71vhxa/. If your code is giving errors then open a new doodad